# Why MapReduce process with ORC needs a HIVE class?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, orc

I am implementing a mapreduce process where read, proces and write into orc file, the problem is when I try to read with a map task it produces a error asking for a org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.io.DiskRange Class, when i import hive-exec.3.1.1.jar it works but cluster use another hive version with their old dependencies and it is a wrong solution.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/io/DiskRange
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/io/DiskRange
    at org.apache.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:342)
    at org.apache.orc.mapreduce.OrcInputFormat.createRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingRecordReader.<init>(DelegatingRecordReader.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingInputFormat.createRecordReader(DelegatingInputFormat.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: First of all, are all of your dependencies in agreement? Are you using the right version of MR/ORC for your cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using native orc library for OrcStruct and hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, this caused the exception. Now I am using all libraries from hive.ql.io.orc.

Comment: Dude, can you share your code in pastebin to read the data using hive.ql.io.orc library using Java map reduce?

Comment: I based my code on https://github.com/mayanhui/hive-orc-mr and https://github.com/num3rd/MapreduceDemo